# How to force element overflow Grid within it

Tags: windows-phone-7, layout

I have following layout

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid Height="100" Background="Wheat" Opacity="0.4">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Slider Orientation="Vertical" Height="170" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White" />
            <Button Content="Btn" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In this scenario Grid will clip rest of Slider which overflows Grid. 
So I’m getting result like this
[image]
While I want to get result like this
[image]
So how can I force Slider to overflow Grid without clipping? Is it any alternatives solutions to this? 
In fact I have more complicated layout so using Canvas instead of Grid is now welcome.

Comment: Do you need the outer `Grid` (the "LayoutRoot"), you might be better off changing that to like a `DockPanel` unless you need a grid for another reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a single `Grid` and playing with its childrens' `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` properties.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
             Height="100"
             Fill="Wheat"
             Opacity="0.4" />

  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.RowSpan="2"
              Grid.Column="1">
    <Slider Orientation="Vertical"
            Height="170"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Background="White" />
    <Button Content="Btn"
            Width="100" />
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I can’t have single Grid but using your example I rebuilt my layout.